# Is it possible? To a hide a div based on a cookie (Creating an EU Cookie Law Banner)

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, cookies, row, show-hide

I am trying to get a 'good looking' EU cookie law banner on our website.

For those that do not know.  In the UK and Europe sites that use cookies have to tell the user.  I have looked at several WP plugins but they are all quite intrusive into the design.

I am using my own WP Boostrap Theme.  Above the navigation bar sits a container div with a child row div.

At the moment I hide the child row div when the user clicks on the button using the data-toggle data-target.

This is shown in the code here (as it sits above the navigation this code appears on every page.

```
<div id="container-topline" class="container-fluid bg-moderateblue" style="min-height:2px;">
    <div id="row-cookie" class="row" style="padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:10px;">
        <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-hidden"></div>
        <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-12">
            <div class="col-sm-10 col-xs-12">
                <ul class="fa-ul" style="color:#FFF; font-size:small;">
                <li>
                <i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle fa-li fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <strong>Privacy &amp; Cookies:</strong> This website uses cookies to improve your experience and to provide essential functionality. By continuing to use this website your consent is implied. To view our privacy policy <a href="#" style="font-weight:bold; color:#FFF;"> click here</a>.
                </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-12" style="text-align:center;">           
                <button class="btn btn-default col-md-pull-right" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#row-cookie">
                <i class="fa fa-times" aria-hidden="true"></i> Close Message
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-1 col-xs-hidden"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So far so good.  However it means on every page the user must close the message.  A bit annoying and it takes focus away from the website.

What I would like is a way (and this is where I am stuck) of hiding the #row-cookie for 24 hours after it has been closed.

Is this possible and do you have any tutotrial recommendations to walk me through?

I thought may be a Cookie but Ive looked at some examples of them being used on Stack Overflow at they quite frankly baffle me!

All help greatly appreaciated :) !

Comment: do you use any frameworks or plain old javascript?

Answer (score 2):

When the user closes the banner, set a cookie via Ajax. Using jQuery, it's as simple as doing:

```
jQuery(#row-cookies .fa-times).click(
    jQuery.get("http://link-to-php-file.php");
});
```

For the PHP file, just create one in your theme directory (make sure to use a [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes), if you're not already doing that!)

And then in the PHP file do:

```
<?php 
// Set a cookie to expire in 24 hours
setcookie("closed-cookies", "true", time()+60*60*24, "/");
```

Now, in your template file, you simply see if the cookie is set before printing it.

```
<?php
if(isset($_COOKIE['closed-cookies'])) :
?>

// Cookie banner

<?php
endif;
?>
```

Comment: Hi @lukas-gjetting thank you your answer is great!.So much clearer now.

Comment: with regard to the jQuery can that read (#row-cookies #row-cookies-button) if i were to give the button an id="row-cookies-button",  I am guessing at the moment it set to someone clicking in the font awsome X only?

Comment: @NathanJones Yes, of course. Actually you won't even need the preceeding "#row-cookies" if you do that.

Comment: Hi, it works great in stripped back theme but when I add in google tag manager it causes a conflict and the jquery which i placed in <script> </script> fails is there a reason for this? does it need to be in a seperate file?

Comment: @NathanJones
What kind of conflict? If you're running jQuery in no-conflict, make sure to use jQuery(selector) and jQuery.get, instead of $(selector) and $.get.

Are you getting an error in the console?

Answer (score 0):

```
!(document.cookie.split(";").forEach(function(elem){
   var key = elem.split("=")[0];
   var value = elem.split("=")[1];
   if(key == "privacyRead" && value == "true"){
     // code to hide the div
     document.getElementById("container-topline").style.display = "none"; 
   } 
}))
```

now just add a onclick handler to the privacy-accept button wich will handle the cookie set stuff `document.cookie = "privacyRead=true;" + "expires=" + new Date(new Date().getTime() + 60*1000*60*24)` + hideDiv and you are done

- I've assumed you didn't use any frameworks.

on page load, the first part of the script will check if there is a cookie and if true will hide your div. 
On the cookie set part, we will add an expiration of 1 Day so the cookie wont be there tomorrow.